# The value to the property that is set in the spring bean is getting null when using

Tags: xml, spring, properties, javabeans

This is my beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="file:/C:/local/fts.properties" />

    <bean id="shredFilesUnderTimePeriod" class="com.qvc.supplychain.app.delete.ShredFilesUnderTimePeriod">
        <property name="fileLocation" value="${LOCAL_FILE_DIR}/FileTransferIntegrationServices/ftpArchive"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and this is my application class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ShredFilesUnderTimePeriod {

    public Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private final static int DAYS_LIMIT = 2;

    private String fileLocation;

    private static long currentTimeInMillis;

    public ShredFilesUnderTimePeriod() {
        shredFilesFromDirectory();
    }

    private void shredFilesFromDirectory() {
        logger.info("Deleting the obsolete files");
        currentTimeInMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        Date currentDate = new Date(currentTimeInMillis);
        logger.info("Today's date: " + "" + currentDate + "\n");
        try {
            File loadFilesFromTheDirectory = new File(fileLocation);
            if (!loadFilesFromTheDirectory.isDirectory()) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Is not a directory");
            } else {
                for (File file : loadFilesFromTheDirectory.listFiles()) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        for (File subDirectoryFile : file.listFiles()) {
                            deleteFile(subDirectoryFile);
                        }
                    } else {
                        deleteFile(file);
                    }
                }
                logger.info("Obsolete files deletion got completed");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException eMsg) {
            eMsg.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception eMsg) {
            logger.error("Error while shredding obsolete files. Cause: " + eMsg.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println("Error while shredding obsolete files. Cause: " + eMsg.getStackTrace());
        } finally {
            //System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private void deleteFile(File file) {
        long totalNumberOfDays = 0L;
        Date fileCreatedDate = null;
        try {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Is not a directory");
            }
            fileCreatedDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
            logger.info(file.getName() + " file is created or last modified on: " + fileCreatedDate
                    + ", total number of days present: " + totalNumberOfDays);
            totalNumberOfDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(currentTimeInMillis - fileCreatedDate.getTime(),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (totalNumberOfDays > DAYS_LIMIT) {
                file.delete();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException eMsg) {
            eMsg.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception eMsg) {
            logger.error("Error while shredding obsolete files. Cause: " + eMsg.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    public String getFileLocation() {
        return fileLocation;
    }

    public void setFileLocation(String fileLocation) {
        this.fileLocation = fileLocation;
    }

}
```

now the problem is the fts.properties file is getting loaded but the value to the property: "fileLocation" is not getting set. I am getting puzzled that even after I tried giving a direct value, its still showing null while debugging. I wish to know where it is going wrong. I want this field/property's value to be set dynamically. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: properties are set after the constructor call. So you can't invoke the method in he constructor and think to have the fileLocation filled. You should create an init-method to be alled after the properties set

Comment: Lots of thanks to you. It is working!!

Comment: try using the Autowired annotation over the setter fileLocation. and use Value annotation to pass the file path. <context:annotation-config> should be used in configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Angelo Immediata in the comment I tried using the init-method attribute and I can now see the code working. Changes that I did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="file:/C:/MY_QVC/fts.properties" />

    <bean id="shredFilesUnderTimePeriod" class="com.qvc.supplychain.app.delete.ShredFilesUnderTimePeriod" init-method="shredFilesFromDirectory">
        <property name="fileLocation" value="${LOCAL_FILE_DIR}/FileTransferIntegrationServices/ftpArchive"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and I have removed the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In fact this Filelocation w'll be always null in your case,  the simple reason is what they mention in spring documentation

> The Spring container validates the configuration of each bean as the container is created. However, the bean properties themselves are not set until the bean is actually created.

check  [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-instantiation)

In your java code  you make use of this property in the constructor before it has been set by the container

You can solve that by multiple ways, one of them is to create a constructor with String argument and change property in xml to construct-arg

```
 <constructor-arg name="fileLocation" value="${LOCAL_FILE_DIR}/FileTransferIntegrationServices/ftpArchive"></constructor-arg>
```

Set your property in the constructor and make use of it - you make it required as any other dependency